# EGit with LDAP: Invalid author specified. Please use the form: A U Thor <author@example.com>

Tags: eclipse, git, ldap, gitlab, egit

I am using EGit on Eclipse Neon 4.6.0 for JavaEE developer. I use LDAP, Windows 10 pro for authenicaion with GitLab CE server. I have been set `user.name`, `user.email` inside Egit configuration, but still error. Error message:

```
EGit: Invalid author specified. Please use the form: A U Thor <author@example.com>
```

[image]

How to overcome this warning?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** Try to commit at least 1 time from command line.
Since my computer use LDAP, when commit, push to server, even, I don't need enter password. Because my computer is my identification.

**Step 2.**  At last commit from Egit inside Eclipse, a dialog appear for enter identication information:
[image]